# save_stack_trace_tsk and struct stack_trace is no longer available in Linux 5.2+

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, callstack

In kernel version before 5.2, I use [save_stack_trace_tsk](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/stacktrace.c#L76) to retrieve call stack.

But this method is no longer available in Linux kernel 5.2+, what should I use?

Comment: "But this method is no longer available in Linux kernel 5.X" - Really? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.21/source/arch/x86/kernel/stacktrace.c#L69

Comment: @Tsyvarev Removed in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2.21/source/arch/x86/kernel/stacktrace.c

Comment: More correctly: The function was removed only in **specific architectures**, and x86 is among them. Anyway, newest kernels seems to have [stack_trace_save_tsk](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc1/source/kernel/stacktrace.c#L252) with the similar semantic as `save_stack_trace_tsk`, but it is not available for modules. Also, there is [stack_trace_save](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc1/source/kernel/stacktrace.c#L113), which is available for modules, but works only with the current task. Both functions should work for x86.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I need to retrieve stack for all threads with `do_each_thread`, but the new function does not seem to use task_struct as a parameter

Comment: Yes, the function `stack_trace_save` works only with the current task. In my previous comment I put wrong reference to the function `stack_trace_save_tsk`. The correct one is [kernel/stacktrace.c:137](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc1/source/kernel/stacktrace.c#L137). It contains "useful" function definition (instead of warning about not supporting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself:

```
unsigned long store[64];

int len = stack_trace_save_tsk(current, store, 64, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
    pr_info("stack at %p\n", store[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This question seemed so tempting so I did some digging here is my findings.

***TLDR; stack_trace_save*() functions replaced by arch_stack_walk() interfaces***

this is part of consolidation plan and remove duplicate code.
[linux commit 214d8ca6ee854](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/214d8ca6ee854f696f75e75511fe66b409e656db) provide common architecture to walking stack trace.

the new interface called `arch_stack_walk`.
made it more generic.
this happened on 25th Apr 2019. and as per [Kernel release History Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_version_history)
It was last changed in 5.1. in [linux commit 3599fe12a125f](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3599fe12a125fa7118da2bcc5033d7741fb5f3a1).

answer your last question

```
what should I use?
```

[save_stack_trace_tsk](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/kernel/stacktrace.c#L66)  ->  [stack_trace_save_tsk](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/kernel/stacktrace.c#L129)

have different function declaration.