# How to get the syscall that currently works?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am a new to linux kernel coding,so now i am writing function that i need to know which syscall is working now ,to build the function according to which system call is executing? so is there a variable or struct that carry which system call number (NR) that is being executed now ?

Comment: "is there a variable or struct that carry which system call number (NR) that is being executed now?" - Definitely, there is no such variable. You may try, however, to extract from the call stack the first function: if the process performs the syscall, the first function will be the syscall function. Knowing the address of the syscall function, you may try to convert it to the system call number using some table. Note, that not every thread in the Linux kernel starts from the system call.

Comment: that means if i am sure that this function called by a certain systemcall so if i can extract stack is it a must that first function is syscall function ? and there is a way to get the stack or to get the first function in the stack? @Tsyvarev

Comment: You could use `save_stack_trace` for obtain an array of return addresses of functions. In the newer kernels the function `save_stack_trace` is replaced with `stack_trace_save`. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459803/save-stack-trace-tsk-and-struct-stack-trace-is-no-longer-available-in-linux-5-2.